# Insert or Update Custom Metadata Type Boolean Field

Tags: custom-field, custom-metadata, boolean

How, or can we, update Custom Metadata Types that have a checkbox field using the MDAPI? When I set it to '1' or 'true' in both instances it says

> value not of required type:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <label>AsmHst00510</label>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <values>
        <field>hdone__AuditSettingMapping__c</field>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">ASM74</value>
    </values>
    **<values>
        <field>hdone__IsActive__c</field>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">yes</value>
    </values>**
</CustomMetadata>
```

hdone__IsActive__c is a boolean field. Have tried:
"TRUE, true, 1, yes"
Each results in an error when using SFDX mdapi:deploy

> IsActive: value not of required type: yes

I saw this Known Issue but these fields are not > 30 characters anyway. Seemed to happen regardless.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bS6AAI

Comment: The KI you linked is not apparently related to your issue. Can you please post a demonstration file of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are specifying incorrect data type.

```
<values>
    <field>hdone__IsActive__c</field>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">yes</value>
</values>
```

If you provide data type as string, then even if you are providing the value as True, it will throw invalid type error.

Change this to the following and see if it works.

```
<values>
    <field>hdone__IsActive__c</field>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
</values>
```

Comment: Aargh! Why I missed this is that the xml file is auto created when I extract the MDT from our org. In this case it was a DX extension though I think in other cases it was the unofficial Custom Metadata Loader.